# Prevent Iceweasel from allowing sites to override default shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox, iceweasel

For example, I use Ctrl-L to mark the URL field. On some sites, this is overridden to do something else. How do I make this never happen?

Comment: Turn off JavaScript, unfortunately.

Comment: You may be able to do this with [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/).

Answer (score 1):

See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Ui.key.contentAccess

You can go to `about:config`, search for `ui.key.contentAccess`, and set it to 0, or for instance 12 (4+8) to only allow <kbd>Meta</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Comment: What should happen if I set it to 0? I just did, and it didn't seem to change anything.